# Powershell Copy-Item fails on User\Documents with Access Denied

Tags: powershell, windows-8

I have a simple backup script to copy the Documents folder to an external hard drive:

```
Copy-Item C:\Users\Username\Documents G:\Backup -Recurse -Force
```

However, when I run the command, Windows 8 is raising an UnauthorizedAccessException for the folders `'...\Documents\My Music'`, `'...\Documents\My Pictures'`, and `'...\Documents\My Videos'`. However, these folders are just symbolic links, which I assume is what is causing the error. How can I avoid copying symbolic links?

**Edit:** Even using a hard-coded Exclude list does not work. Full script is below:

```
$backupFolder = (get-date -uformat %Y%m%d)
$lines = Get-Content backup.cfg

$DirLinks = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Videos", "C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Music","C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Pictures"
$basePath = $lines[0] + $backupFolder + "\"
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $lines.Length; $i++)
{
    $lines[$i]
    Copy-Item $lines[$i] ($basePath + ($lines[$i].Replace(":", ""))) -Recurse -Force -Exclude $DirLinks
}

"Done!"
```

I still get the following errors:

```
    Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Music' is denied.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\backup app\backup.ps1:20 char:5
+     Copy-Item $lines[$i] ($basePath + ($lines[$i].Replace(":", ""))) -Recurse -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Music:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Pictures' is denied.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\backup app\backup.ps1:20 char:5
+     Copy-Item $lines[$i] ($basePath + ($lines[$i].Replace(":", ""))) -Recurse -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Pictures:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Videos' is denied.
At C:\Users\Me\Desktop\backup app\backup.ps1:20 char:5
+     Copy-Item $lines[$i] ($basePath + ($lines[$i].Replace(":", ""))) -Recurse -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Videos:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to avoid symbolic links.

First you need to find them:

```
$DirLinks = Get-ChildItem C:\SomeDir -Recurse | ? { $_.Attributes -like "*ReparsePoint*" } | % { $_.FullName }
```

Then exclude them:

```
Copy-Item C:\SomeDir D:\Backup -Recurse -Force -Exclude $DirLinks
```

Comment: It appears that $DirLinks is empty when I apply it to the Documents path.

Comment: In fact, just running `Get-ChildItem C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents -Recurse` does not show any of the symlinks. However, they are still causing trouble when calling Copy-Item with the same parameters.

Comment: Alrighty, that's weird. Symbolic, directory and junction links will have a "ReparsePoint" listed in the Attributes property. Can you go ahead and "(Get-ChildItem C:\KnownFailingLink).Attributes" and see what shows up? If it's a directory link, it should say Directory, ReparsePoint. If it's Access Denied, you have a different issue.

Comment: Are we talking NTFS or is this a different filesystem? The only kind of link that won't have a "ReparsePoint" attribute is a HardLink, but those should still appear when you're listing the directory with GCI.

Comment: I'm still getting access denied. It's really strange, because I have triple-checked that I am running Powershell ISE as admin. It's a new Windows 8 installation -- which I believe is NTFS.

Comment: Do you have those directories linked manually, or are they default folders?

Comment: All just default folders. It's a brand new install.

Comment: Alright - well before we go any further, just note that my answer should work if you build the array of directories to exclude manually - but I'm guessing you will want to back that data up. 
e.g. $ArrayToExclude = "C:\Users\You\Music","C:\Users\You\Downloads" 

However, in the interest of finding out what's happening - let's do some testing. Try reading from the "My Music" folder -- 
Copy-Item C:\..\My Music\Sample.mp3 C:\TestFolder  -- then try writing to the backup drive -- 
Copy-Item C:\TestFolder\Sample.mp3 D:\Backup\..\My Music\

Comment: Apparently even hard-coding the Exclude paths does not work. See edit in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the script as admin?  Also I assume the user running the script is also the same user that would fit in the username area?

Comment: Yes, I am running it as admin.